# Sum by variable name does not work when given as input$ in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below which is supposed to sum `Frequency` by the selected `Category`. But for some reason `input$investigate` is not recognized. When I run the code of aggregation out of the shiny app it works. I give you the dataset as well below the app. It is a naming issue or a shiny issue? This is what I wonder.

```
x <- data.frame(CategoryA=factor(c("First", "First", "First", "Second",
                                  "Third", "Third", "Second")),
                CategoryB=factor(c("First", "First", "First", "Second",
                                    "Third", "Third", "Second")),
                Frequency=c(10,15,5,2,14,20,3))


summ<-data.frame(aggregate(x$Frequency, by=list(x$CategoryA), FUN=sum))
```

## app

```
library(shiny)
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('k-means '),
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("inv")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("tab1")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$inv<-renderUI({
    radioButtons("investigate", label ="Select Category", 
                 choices = colnames(x)[1:2], 
                 selected = "CategoryA")
  })

  datasett<-reactive({
    summ<-data.frame(aggregate(Frequency ~ input$investigate, x, sum))
    summ
  })
  output$tab1<-renderDataTable({
    datasett()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are passing a formula to aggregate `Frequency ~ input$investigate` but also note that `input$investigate` returns a character values, not a "variable" with a value. You are basically running

```
data.frame(aggregate(Frequency ~ "CategoryA", x, sum))
```

which doesn't work. You need to create a proper formula like

```
data.frame(aggregate(Frequency ~ CategoryA, x, sum))
```

The easiest way to do this is with the `reformulate()` command which can turn character values into formulas. Update your code to use

```
data.frame(aggregate(reformulate(input$investigate,"Frequency"), x, sum))
```

Comment: what if there are more than one input$?